# What does "a'me" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, contractions

> Only boss a'me, is me.

What is the meaning of "a'me" in the above sentence?

[image]

Comment: You may also see it rendered "o' me", which makes it clearer that it is indicating the pronunciation of the phrase "of me," as Daniel explained below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'a' is just a representation of the word "of" as it might be pronounced. In other words, it's just "of me".